# Dimension of homomorphism between 2 representation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose for a finite group $G$, there are two representations, namely $(\rho,M),(\sigma,N)$, where $M,N$ is vector space over field $K$ and $\rho: G\to M,\;\sigma :G\to N$ are the maps. Now I'm asked to verify the equation:

> $\dim_K(\text{Hom}_G(M,N))=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} \text{tr}(\rho(g^{-1}))\text{tr}(\sigma(g))$

I have no idea about it. The right side seems to be a kind of inner products, or maybe I should find some invariants?

Comment: What do you have from the course? Schur's lemma, direct sums of representations, Maschke's theorem? Help us out. Because this is a standard result from representation theory, proved as part of any course.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I learned Schur's lemma and direct sum of representations. I'll go google Maschke's theorem and check my textbook. Would you mind telling me the keypoint?

Comment: I googled Maschke's theorem. And that's it. Thanks.